# How to filter eager loading constraints plus top LIKE filter

Tags: laravel, eloquent

I have 2 tables: **auctions** and **properties**. a one-to-many relation. each auction contains many properties.

I'm trying to query **properties** directly but I need to apply *WHERE* clause to 2 columns: **property.desc** and **auction.code** using *LIKE*.

This is what I have:

```
Property::with(['auction'=>function($query) use ($search) {
                $query->orWhere('code', 'LIKE', "%$search%");
            }])->
            where('desc','LIKE', "%$search%")
                ->paginate(10);
```

The problem is that the first query eloquent executes is:

```
SELECT count(*) as aggregate FROM "properties" WHERE "desc"::text LIKE '%df3432sf%'
```

Since that query doesn't fetch anything, Eloquent doesn't go any further (I expect applying the filter over **auction.code** as well.

This is easily done with raw SQL:

```
select * from properties p
JOIN auctions a ON a."id" = p.auction_id
WHERE a.code LIKE '%x%'
OR p.desc LIKE '%x%'
```

Any idea?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

May be this will work as I am not sure about your flow of data of your application

code:

```
Property::with('auction', function($q) use($search) {
            $q->where('code', 'LIKE', "%".$search."%");
        })->where('desc','LIKE', "%".$search."%")->get();
```

But this will gives only those auction ( optional ) whose property desc will match your search parameter which will make the whole query little complex so I will recommend to go through auction to properties because auction has many properties as you mentioned.
Assuming your auction model is name Auction
Code:

```
Auction::with('properties', function($q) use ($search) {
                             $q->where('desc','LIKE', "%".$search."%");
                      })->where('code', 'LIKE', "%".$search."%")->get();
```

or If you need even more power, you may use the whereHas and orWhereHas methods to put "where" conditions on your has queries

```
Property::where('desc','LIKE', "%".$search."%")->orWhereHas('auction', function($q) use($search){ $q->where('code', 'LIKE', "%".$search."%") })->get();
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: The last example works exactly as expected. It requires 4 queries but not a big deal. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

I would do something like:

```
Property::whereRaw('LOWER(`desc`) LIKE ?', '%'.strtolower($search).'%')
    orWhereHas('auction', function($query) use ($search) {
        $query->whereRaw('LOWER(`code`) LIKE ?', '%'.strtolower($search).'%')
    })->paginate(10);
```